# SQL Server 2016 output comma seperated list of table names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, coalesce

I have the following T-SQL query (which will be inside a stored procedure):

```
DECLARE @columnNames nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT 
    @columnNames = COALESCE(@columnNames + ',','') + sC.name 
FROM 
    sys.columns sC
JOIN 
    sys.tables AS sT ON sT.object_id = sC.object_id
WHERE 
    sC.name NOT IN (SELECT name 
                    FROM sys.identity_columns 
                    WHERE is_identity = 1)
    AND sT.name = 'Audit' 
ORDER BY 
    sC.column_id 

INSERT INTO [B2017].[dbo].[Audit] (@columnNames) 
VALUES ('')
```

If I run just this:

```
DECLARE @columnNames nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT 
    @columnNames = COALESCE(@columnNames + ',','') + sC.name 
FROM 
    sys.columns sC
JOIN 
    sys.tables AS sT
ON 
    sT.object_id = sC.object_id
WHERE 
    sC.name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE is_identity = 1)
AND 
    sT.name = 'Audit' 
ORDER BY 
    sC.column_id
```

It displays as it should:

```
columnName1,columnName2,columnName3,etc...
```

However, what I want to do is output that `(@columnNames)` into an `INSERT INTO` so that I can dynamically change the `Audit` table column names at any time without needing to edit the stored procedure.

So taking the example column names above, this is what I am trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO [B2017].[dbo].[Audit] (columnName1, columnName2, columnName3,etc...) 
VALUES ('somevalue1,somevalue2,somevalue3,...')
```

When trying the full code above (that's including the INSERT INTO) I get this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
>   Invalid column name '@columnNames'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found a working method:

```
INSERT INTO 
    [B2017].[dbo].[Audit] OUTPUT (@columnNames)
VALUES 
    ('somevalue1,somevalue2,somevalue3,...')
```

That works as I am needing it to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
INSERT INTO [B2017].[dbo].[Audit] ([columnNames]) 
    VALUES ('''')
';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[columnNames]', '@columnNames')

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Having said that, this code still will not work.  You are passing one value into `values`, but have multiple columns.  You need to adjust the values to be correct.

Comment: Also you have to remove the extra coma from the columnNames.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement dynamic query like below :

```
execute('INSERT INTO [B2017].[dbo].[Audit] (' + @columnNames + ') VALUES('''')')
```